# Cannot resolve method 'setupWithNavController...'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a BottomNavigationBar in my Android app, and I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'setupWithNavController(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView, androidx.navigation.NavController)'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong since these 3 lines of code in the activity are found in many nav bar guides online.

**Activity Code Segment in Question**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    BottomNavigationItemView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);    //cannot resolve this
    }
```

**Relevant Dependencies**

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.1"
```

**activity_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NavigationActivity">


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**bottom_nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/settingsNavFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
    android:title="Settings" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/homeNavFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
    android:title="Home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/groupsNavFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_groups_24"
    android:title="Groups" />
</menu>
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/homeNavFragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeNavFragment"
    android:name="com.example.foodwithfriends.HomeNavFragment"
    android:label="fragment_home_nav"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_nav" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/settingsNavFragment"
    android:name="com.example.foodwithfriends.settingsNavFragment"
    android:label="fragment_settings_nav"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings_nav" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/groupsNavFragment"
    android:name="com.example.foodwithfriends.GroupsNavFragment"
    android:label="fragment_groups_nav"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_groups_nav" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've casted your `BottomNavigationView` incorrectly.

Replace

```
BottomNavigationItemView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
```

With

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just check u import right library. U need to add AndroidX library.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).